# phpmyadmin login page half loading

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I have local mysql server set up under Ubuntu Linux, I was using phpmyadmin for quiet some time now, but suddenly I am not able to log in anymore, when I get to the page it displays phpmyadmin logo with "Welcome to phpMyAdmin" text beneath it and that's it, no inputs to type my credidentials to. It's strange cuz I didn't made any changes since last using it, no package updates or anything.

So far I tried to access it from another browser, rebooting server and even reinstalling phpmyadmin, no luck so far. And a strange thing I noticed is that when I get to the console on the phpmyadmin page there's a bunch of errors, don't know if that's releated or no but here it is:

> get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:6172 [Deprecation] Synchronous
>   XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its
>   detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check
>   https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

,

> /phpmyadmin/js/get_s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:3062 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid
>   or unexpected token

,

> get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:5982 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   PMA_commonParams is not defined
>       at error_handler (get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:6977)
>       at notifyHandlers (get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:5974)
>       at traceKitWindowOnError (get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:6020)

,

> 192.168.88.60/:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: PMA_commonParams is not defined
>       at 192.168.88.60/:2

,

> get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:5982 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   PMA_commonParams is not defined
>       at error_handler (get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:6977)
>       at notifyHandlers (get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:5974)
>       at traceKitWindowOnError (get_scripts.js.php?s…1deb2ubuntu2.1:6020)

Comment: Do you see anything useful if you View Source... on the login page in your browser?

Comment: If you're getting syntax errors it's possible your installation is trashed. Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes I tried reinstalling it, it didn't help. However problem magically disappeard after 2 hours or so, I did literally nothing, and these errors I was getting disappeared as well. I wonder what it was, from those error massages I get it had something to do with AJAX requests, perhaps part of login page is not hardcoded into php script but generated by JS. But what caused those errors is unknown to me, maybe there is actually a bug in source code